# How do I view the list of files which are being checked out

Tags: git

When I clone a instance, I get an output like this. How do I view the list of files which are being checked out (much similar to SVN)

```
remote: Counting objects: 119, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (72/72), done.
Receiving objects:  27% (33/119), 1.49 MiB | 74 KiB/s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's an option to `git clone` that does that - the verbose option doesn't cause any more output at the "Checking out files" stage.  However, you can just change into the directory afterwards and type:

```
git ls-files
```

... to see every file in the working tree that was created by the clone.

Comment: I feel its extremely limiting that this information cannot be shown on a clone operation.

Comment: If you want to see a delta later on, you can do: `git fetch origin` and then `git diff master origin/master` to see the difference between your most recent commit and the version of master from the remote.  That doesn't touch your working tree, as a `git pull` would.

Comment: I'd be interested in what the use case is for seeing the files that are being checked out.  Usually, the part that takes the most time is fetching objects rather than checking-out the master branch, and the objects are typically compressed into pack files for very efficient transfer.  The pack files use binary delta compression, so it isn't necessarily clear how you *would* show the progress of fetching objects accurately on a file-by-file basis.

Comment: I agree it compresses the objects on transfer, but I would be more comfortable if I can view the files which are being checked out. I wouldn't care, if its going to take a little bit more time doing that (its an usability issue for me)